# How do I copy the list of files from a global search in Xcode to an editor?

Tags: xcode

I would like the results from `find navigator` in an external list so I can freely organize/mark them. Is there a way to do this?

I have tried copying them but there is no 'paste' option for programs useful for dealing with lists, such as Excel.